# When to use <T> in generic method's declaration

Tags: java, generics, methods

What is the difference between this:

```
T getById(Integer id);
```

And this:

```
<T> T getById(Integer id);
```

Are they not both returning a class with type `T`?

Comment: The first is the class type parameter, the second is the method type parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, but you will have to declare `T` somewhere. What changes is where you do.

- In the first case, `T` is defined at class level, so your method is part of a generic class and you will have to specialize the class when you declare/instantiate. `T` will be the same for all methods and attributes in the class.
- In the second, `T` is defined at method level, so it's a generic method. Value for `T` can (often) be deduced.

In the first case, the scope of `T` is the whole class, while in the second is the method only.

The second form is used commonly with static methods. Also, the latter has the advantage that the type variable `T` can be deduced (you don't have to specify it in most cases), while you have to specify it for the former.

Specifically, you will have to use a generic class if some attributes of it depend on `T` (are of type `T`, `List<T>`, etc.).

Comment: So the 2nd one is introducing a new TYPE to be used solely in that particular method right?

Comment: @MikaelS. Technically a new type *variable*, but yes, its scope is only that method.

Comment: Yep, as @MikaelS. said.

Answer (score 8):

In the first snippet, `T` is referring to the type variable declared in the class' type parameter list.

In the second snippet, you are creating a new type variable `T` (which may shadow the class one), declared in the method parameter list.

Answer (score 7):

The first one returns the type T of the enclosing generic type. For example,

```
T get(int index);
```

declared in class `List<T>` returns the element of type T at the given index of the `List<T>`.

The second one declares that the method itself is a generic method, whose returned type depends on the way it's invoked. If you invoke it as

```
String s = theObject.<String>getById(id);
```

it will return a String. If you invoke it as

```
Foo f = theObject.<Foo>getById(id);
```

it will return a Foo. Most of the time, the generic type is inferred automatically by the compiler, so you can simply write

```
Foo f = theObject.getById(id);
```

For a concrete example, see

```
static <T> T max(Collection<? extends T> coll, Comparator<? super T> comp)
```

which returns the maximum element, of type T, in a collection of T. The type returned by the method depends on the type of the collection passed to the method.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain well when its used, I am providing an example

For point 1

```
class ArrayList<E> {//implementing and extending
   public E get(int index) {
   }
}
```

For point 2 : Static utility method

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
    return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```